# pandas to_datetime is only converting some columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert a column in a dataframe to DateTime using data from a csv

```
DATE
9/7/2012    
10/18/2019
10/2/2015
10/4/2015
4/25/2013
```

with this code

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], errors='coerce',format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Only about half of the rows are successfully being converted to datetime, and the rest to NaT

It looks like this

```
DATE
2012-07-09
NaT
2015-02-10
2015-04-10
NaT
```

How do I fix this? Or could this be a problem with my with my data source?

Comment: You're formatting wrong. You need "%m/%d/%Y"

Comment: Why passing `format` when `to_datetime` can parse what you are passing automatically :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang it's much quicker when you specify format, so good practice I assume. also rules out inferred error when working with multiple datetime formats.

Comment: @QuangHoang It may cause problem if you are used to day/month/year and the data is month/day/year (personal experience)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], errors='coerce',format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

If the month is bigger than 12 pandas will return NaT, that's what happens when you run your code.